# setting up the 'inc' directory for a dist using Module::Package

Tags: perl, cpan, perl-module

As an example, the CPAN distribution `Scalar-Does-0.006` uses `Module::Package` in its `Makefile.PL`, and the code for `Module::Package` resides in the sub-directory `inc` with files like:

```
inc/Module/AutoInstall.pm
inc/Module/Install/AutoInstall.pm
inc/Module/Install/AutoManifest.pm
inc/Module/Install/Base.pm
...
```

Question: If I want to use `Module::Package` for my own distribution, is there a convenient way to populate the `inc` directory with the files my distribution needs? I have `Module::Package` installed locally in my perl's site_perl directory.

I can't seem to find the answer in the `Module::Package` docs.

Answer: Just create your `Makefile.PL`, and running it (i.e. `perl Makefile.PL`) will populate the `inc` directory.

Answer (score 0):

[Module::Package](https://metacpan.org/module/Module%3a%3aPackage) is an extension of [Module::Install](https://metacpan.org/module/Module%3a%3aInstall).  It doesn't repeat the Module::Install docs, just the bits it adds.  Read the [Module::Install docs](https://metacpan.org/module/Module%3a%3aInstall).

Unless you need the extensions provided by Module::Package, I would recommend you start with Module::Install.  Module::Install does all the bundling stuff, has tons of plugins, has been around for years, and has a huge number of users.  Switch to Module::Package later if you need it, it should be a drop in replacement.